# Do not load the site as soon as you enter the WordPress panel

Tags: wp-admin

I have a strange problem that when I enter the WordPress admin panel, my site does not load, as soon as I press the WordPress exit button, the site loads well. I am using Windows 10. I changed the DNS and a few other things related to Windows but it didn't work.
I want your help.

Comment: WordPress exit button?

Comment: Are you working locally or on a server where DNS has changed? If it's not local, you may just need to wait for settings to propagate.